# How do I get the regex to return more accurately?

Tags: regex, jq, aws-cli

I am trying to get the regex right to return one or the other but not both:
When I run for example the following:

```
aws secretsmanager list-secrets | jq -r ".SecretList[] | select(.Name|match(\"example-*\")) | .Name "
```

it returns

```
example-secret_key
```

as well as

```
examplecompany-secret_key
```

how can I modify the command to return one and not the other? Thanks

Comment: To me it looks as if the regex simply matches both results. So: what are the rules you want to apply? The current rule matches all names that have inside "example" followed by zero or more (`*`) dashes (`-`)

Comment: Remove the asterisk `*` as in `example-`.

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: Tip: You should be using `test` instead of `match` here since you since want to check if the pattern matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`example-*` matches strings that contain `example` followed by zero or more `-`.

`^example-` matches strings that start with `example-`.

```bash
jq -r '.SecretList[].Name | select( test( "^example-" ) )'
```

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression is not a shell glob/wildcard. `*` in a regex does not mean "anything", but rather "whatever came before is repeated 0 or more times". `.` is a single arbitrary character. `.*` are 0 or more arbitrary characters.

If you want to match "example-" and don't care what comes after, simply use the regex `example-`. If you want to match "example-", then anything or nothing, then "_key", use the regex `example-.*_key`.

```
jq -r '.SecretList[].Name | select(test("example-"))'
```